# Unable to translate GUI in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have written following code to load .ts file

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    #endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QTranslator translator;

    if(translator.load("<absolute-path>/translating-qml_ge.qm"))
    {
        qDebug() << "Loaded";
        app.installTranslator(&translator);
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "failed";



    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

I have checked return value of 'installTranslator' which is true.
but still UI is not getting translated.

Comment: You should load binary language files (*.qm), not *.ts. Load your *.ts file into Qt Linguist and then `lrelease` to get *.qm file.See [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application) page for more info.

Comment: I have loaded .qm file but still ui is not getting translated

Comment: So that means that you do something wrong. As I remember you should set right locale using `QLocale`. Otherwise Qt will be unable to determine what translation to use.